# connections between Grothendieck's and Serre's duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, duality

Hi, 
I would like to show that 
if $f: X \rightarrow Y=Spec \, \mathbb{C}$, where $X$ is a nonsingular complex projective variety, is the projection to a point, then the complex $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y$, appearing in Grothendieck's duality, is the dualizing sheaf for $X$. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Starting from
$ Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(F, f^! \mathcal{O}_Y) \simeq  Hom_{{O}_Y}(Rf_* F, \mathcal{O}_Y) $
applying the cohomology functor $ H^i $ we obtain
$Ext^i(F, f^! \mathcal{O}_Y) \simeq Ext^i(Rf_* F, \mathcal{O}_Y).$
Using Yoneda's Formula, the right term becomes
$Hom^i_{D(Y)}(Rf_* F, \mathcal{O}_Y) \cong Hom_{D(Y)}(Rf_* F, \mathcal{O}_Y[i]) \cong Hom(\widetilde{H^1(X,F)}[-i], \mathcal{O}_Y),$ where, for the last isomorphism, I use Theorem 8.5 from Hartshorne'a Algebraic Geometry, p.251.
Now, by Corollary 5.5 pag.151 from Hartshorne, and remembering that $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)= \mathbb{C}$, the last term is equal to $Hom(H^1(X,F)[-i], \mathbb{C}) = H^{1-i}(X,F)'$. 
Now, we have $Hom^i_{D(X)}(F, f^! \mathcal{O}_Y) \cong H^{1-i}(X,F)'$ and, shifting by $(-n+1-i)$, $Hom(F, f^! \mathcal{O_Y}[-n+1]) \cong H^n(X,F)'$. So, $f^!(\mathcal{O}_Y)[-n+1]$ is a dualizing sheaf for $X$. But we know that, for a nonsingular projective variety the (unique) dualizing sheaf is the canonical sheaf $\omega$. Thus, we must have $f^!\mathcal{O}_Y[-n+1] \cong \omega$, then $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y = \omega[n-1]$.

I should obtain $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y = \omega[n]$... what's wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I'm too lazy to check through the whole thing, but certainly  your identification $Rf_*F= \widetilde{H^1(X,F)}$ isn't right.


Comment: emmy, how do you define the dualizing sheaf for $X$?  Do you just want to show it satisfies the usual Serre duality?

Comment: I mean, if you look up $f^!$ for a smooth morphism, then the fact that $f^! O_Y$ (if $Y= \text{Spec } \mathbb{C}$) is the dualzing sheaf (with a shift) is often completely tautological.  See for example Residues and Duality.  

Comment: By dualizing sheaf I mean a sheaf that satisfies the usual Serre's duality (definition p.241 Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry). I read the proof of duality for smooth morphisms from Residues and Duality, but I need the proof of Grothendieck's duality from this article http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-01/S0894-0347-96-00174-9/ and I was trying to compute $f^! \mathcal{O}_Y $ in that particular case, just using this and classical Serre's duality. Thank you 

Comment: If you just want to find the mistake in the argument above, then you could try specialising it to the case where $X$ is a point and $n=0$ :-) because I reckon that even in this degenerate case $\omega$ is non-zero (I guess it's the structure sheaf).

Comment: Couldn't resist trying this myself and I got unstuck at the same point Donu Arapura mentioned above. 

Comment: The identity `$R^if_*(F) \cong \widetilde{H^i(X,F)}$` is right for a morphism `$ f: X \rightarrow Y$` from a noetherian to an affine scheme, where $F$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. (See Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, page 251, Thm. 8.5) 

Comment: emmy, that's right, but how are you getting $H^1$?  You should get $\widetilde{R \Gamma(X, F) }$.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand this point. The cohomology functors `$H^i(X,-)$` are, by definition, the right derived functors of the global section `$ \Gamma(X,-)$`. So, for `$i=1$` don't I get `$R \Gamma(X,F) \cong H^1(X,F)$`?

Comment: emmy, no, you definitely don't get that.  $R\Gamma(X,F)$ is a complex (an object in the derived category).  You get $h^1(R \Gamma(X, F)) = H^1(X,F)$.  In particular, one of the cohomologies of that complex is what you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you to you all. :) I will try to solve the problem in another way.

Comment: In "Residues and duality" one proves Grothendieck's duality by showing some particular cases (smooth, finite morphism...) and then reducing the general case to them. Here is simple to show that `$f^!\mathcal{O}_Y$` is the shifted canonical sheaf. But, if one proves Grothendieck's duality for a proper morphism in a more general way, without using this special cases (see for example Neeman's article I cited), is there a way to recover that `$f^!\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \omega[n]$` as a special case, without proving that the shifted canonical sheaf satisfies the duality? I hope my question is clear...

Answer (score 5):

The proof that if $f \colon X \to Y$ is proper and smooth then $f^!\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \Omega^n_F[n]$ ($n=$ dim. rel.$(f)$) assuming only the existence of $f^!$ follows from theorem 3 in

Verdier, Jean-Louis 
Base change for twisted inverse image of coherent sheaves. 
1969 Algebraic Geometry (Internat. Colloq., Tata Inst. Fund. Res., Bombay, 1968) pp. 393–408 Oxford Univ. Press, London.

The proof relies on the "fundamental local isomorphism" and several formal properties of $f^!$. Hope it helps.